# XML scan from C# to F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

Trying to learning F# and I tried to reimplement the following function in F#

```
private string[] GetSynonyms(string synonyms)
{
    var items = Enumerable.Repeat(synonyms, 1)
                          .Where(s => s != null)
                          .Select(XDocument.Parse)
                          .Select(doc => doc.Root)
                          .Where(root => root != null)
                          .SelectMany(e => e.Elements(SynonymsNamespace + "synonym"))
                          .Select(e => e.Value)
                          .ToArray();

    return items;
}
```

I got this far by myself

```
let xname = XNamespace.Get "http://localuri"

let syn = "<synonyms xmlns=\"http://localuri\"><synonym>a word</synonym><synonym>another word</synonym></synonyms>"

let synonyms str =
    let items = [str]
    items
    |> List.map System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse
    |> List.map (fun x -> x.Root)
    |> List.map (fun x -> x.Elements(xname + "synonym") |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>)
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x)
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Value)

let a = synonyms syn

Dump a
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a more-functional way to write the same code.

By extracting the access to the properties to standalone functions I got this version

```
let xname = XNamespace.Get "http://localuri"

let syn = "<synonyms xmlns=\"http://localuri\"><synonym>a word</synonym><synonym>another word</synonym></synonyms>"

let getRoot (doc:System.Xml.Linq.XDocument) = doc.Root

let getValue (element:System.Xml.Linq.XElement) = element.Value

let getElements (element:System.Xml.Linq.XElement) =
    element.Elements(xname + "synonym")
        |> Seq.cast<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>

let synonyms str =
    let items = [str]
    items
    |> List.map System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse
    |> List.map getRoot
    |> List.map getElements
    |> Seq.collect (fun x -> x)
    |> Seq.map getValue

let a = synonyms syn

Dump a
```

But I still have a few concerns

1. Can I rewrite that Seq.collect (fun x -> x) in another way? It sounds redundant
2. Can I remove all those (fun x -> x.Property) without creating new functions?
3. How to actually return an array and not a Seq<'a> (which I understand is an IEnumerable<'a>)

Thanks

Comment: Adding to answer below: 3. Array.ofSeq

Comment: Alternatively you can directly use collect with a composition of the different function steps ; example in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BxD1J2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Seq.collect (fun x -> x) can be rewritten with the predefined id function to Seq.collect id
2. In F# 4.0 it can be removed for constructors only.
3. use Seq.toArray or Seq.toList

Answer (score 1):

Would it be very wrong to drop the C#-code and go all in with the XML-provider in F#? In my world its **always** wrong to parse XML when there exists other solutions (unless Im trying to create octogonal wheels or moist gun powders other have made better before me).

In this regard I would even have used some transformation (XSLT) or selection (XPATH/XQUERY) unless I could use the XML-provider or some XSD (c#) for generating code.

If for some reason the XML is so unstructured that you actually need parsing, then the XML is arguably wrong...

If using the XmlProvider you get namespacing, types etc for free...

```
#r @"..\correct\this\path\to\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"


open FSharp.Data
[<Literal>]
let syn = "<synonyms xmlns=\"http://localuri\"><synonym>a word</synonym><synonym>another word</synonym></synonyms>"

type Synonyms = XmlProvider<syn>

let a = Synonyms.GetSample()

a.Synonyms |> Seq.iter (printfn "%A")
```

Mind that the XmlProvider also can take files or url as examples for inferring types etc, and that you also can have this code as the example and then use

```
let a = Synonyms.Load(stuff)
```

where stuff is a read from stream, textreader or URI and inferred according to your example. The sample and the stuff might even point to same file/Uri if this is some standard placing of data.

See also: http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html

Comment: I see your point and I generally agree with it. The reason behind this specific solution is mostly because I wanted to learn F# and I copied this legacy function I have in the system I'm working on right now :)
In C# world, I'd have used XmlSerializer to read it, I didn't know about XmlProvider<T>, so thanks a lot!